# CoreLocation find distance travelled and use as variable iOS

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, distance

I am making an alarm that shuts off only after the phone has been moved a certain distance(to force the user out of bed). I need to be able to find the distance travelled after the alarm has gone off, then take this distance and use it in a method to shut the alarm sound off if the minimum distance has been travelled. Any ideas? 
I'm using the following to update the location. Any thoughts on how to incorporate this into disabling the alarm?

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
if(!newLocation) {
    NSLog(@"No movement");
}

if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
    (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
{



    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:oldLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:oldLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [loc2 distanceFromLocation:loc1];
    if (distance>=4) {
        NSLog(@"Very good!");
    }

}

NSLog(@"Location:%@", newLocation);
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: I'll post some of the code I'm using. Very new to coding so a bit confused.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting the NSLog "Very good!" This is should only occur if the device moves 4 meters or more, and I am simulating on Macbook Pro so no movement should occur.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You're not considering [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy). First if this is negative for either coordinate, then you just can't do any comparison. And even if they're both non-negative, you probably want to back out the horizontal accuracies if you really want to determine if the user moved a certain distances.

   Look at not only the latitude and longitude, but the [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy), too.
2. You're not considering that when you turn on location services, there are frequently a whole series of coordinates that come in, and the coordinates may bounce around as the horizontal accuracy gets better and better. You want to make sure you don't consider this slow triangulation as the movement necessary to qualify as having gotten out of bed.
3. Make sure you do your experimentation on a real device, in real world scenarios. Using the simulator is definitely not a good test. Nor is using a device plugged into your computer (because you you want to see your GPS in real world scenario, where someone has moved around before going to bed).
4. I'd suggest starting with a simple app that logs location events in a database (or other format) and perhaps show the log in a tableview, so you don't always have to go back to your computer to review the results. Fire up that app, walk around, and then look at the location events you get. That will help you get your arms around the patterns you see as people use their actual devices.
5. Note that if this app is destined for the app store, you'll want to engage lots of different people in different environments and different devices and different scenarios (poor GPS locations, with wifi, no wifi, etc.). Even when you do your own real-world GPS experience with a physical device, you must appreciate that everyone else's may experience different GPS results.
6. I must confess to some reservations whether the iPhone GPS is accurate enough for this sort of app as a generalized solution, and you'll probably want to warn the user to make sure to plug in their iPhone before they go to sleep so the GPS doesn't drain the battery. You might also want to play tricks like turning on location services after the user has demonstrated that they're up and about. You might also not even want to turn on location services until a few minutes before the alarm, thereby assuring that the GPS is as accurate as it can be when the alarm goes off, but not draining their battery as they sleep if they don't happen to have it plugged in and charging.

---

**Update:**

Probably easier than calculating distances yourself, use the location services distance filter (i.e. only generate events when the location changes by *x* meters). For example:

```
- (void)startLocationManager
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5.0; // detect when I move 5 meters
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

When I do that, standing completely still, as soon as I turn on location services, I get a whole bunch of events before I even start moving. You can see the GPS warming up, and getting more and more accurate:

```
 latitude          longitude          horizontalAccuracy
 ----------------  ------------------ ------------------
 39.9482837548282  (82.4963494095571) 65
 39.9482817585030  (82.4964543834170) 10
 39.9482392622539  (82.4964914314290) 5
 39.9481753502422  (82.4964918505242) 5
 39.9481269028419  (82.4964797805836) 5
```

I wait for that to quite down (it took 15-20 seconds in my case), and then I started walking in a straight line, looking at the distance from the last location I got above.

```
 latitude          longitude          horizontalAccuracy distance
 ----------------  ------------------ ------------------ --------
 39.9481722908476  (82.4964962091138) 5                  5.3
 39.9482206544289  (82.4965029146363) 5                  10.4
 39.9482627315828  (82.4965282279839) 5                  15.4
 39.9483157471204  (82.4965248752227) 5                  21.2
```

I must confess that while I didn't measure it, these distances didn't feel quite right, but possibly within the 5 meter tolerance I set up with my `distanceFilter`.

Anyway, as all of this evidences, the right process is probably going to be

- turn on location services, setting the `distanceFilter` appropriate for your app;
- wait for the location to settle down;
- make sure the horizontalAccuracy is even plausible for this process to work at all; and
- wait for the new location notification based upon the GPS determining that the `distanceFilter` has been exceeded.

This never will be perfect (e.g. I had to walk a good 6-10 meters before my "5 meter" `distanceFilter` kicked in, probably a combination of the GPS lagging a few seconds and the `horizontalAccuracy`), but it might be "good enough for government work."

(By the way, I've changed my coordinates in the above log, so don't look for me in this Ohio cornfield, but it gives you and idea of the sort of pattern you may see.)

Comment: So how do I incorporate that into my code and then into an if statement to shut my alarm off? The alarm sound is playing through AVPlayer and I want to call [avSound stop]; when the distance has been reached.

Comment: I'm in high school so it is my bedroom, but yes it is around the same size as a dorm room. Thanks for all the help! I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks again. My iPhone and Xcode operating systems are currently incompatible so I can't do any real world testing at the moment...real pain in the ass.

Comment: @user1004117 It's going to be hard to make much progress until you update your Xcode environment to support your iOS device. The simulator is pretty useless for this level of GPS testing as you don't see the real-world slow process of the GPS locking into your position. Regardless, I've updated my answer with some practical, real-world testing and some additional thoughts. This is obviously only one data point, my iPhone 5 in this imaginary Ohio cornfield :), but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Hi,Mr.Rob, thank you for your answer.And i stuck in to this isssue.I followed your instructions and testing in real ipad,i want to find if this ipad move from the current building in certain distance.And while searching i fount this code but did not get what exactly this return.Is this useful in the current issue. let  interval = newLocation?.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        
        print("interval \(interval)")
        
        if (abs(interval!)>20) {

Comment: In this delegete func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { how can i check the moving data what code need to place here.

Comment: That notion of waiting 20 seconds before you declare the location from `CLLocationManager` valid is a nice simple way of letting it warm up and get a reasonable location. I'd personally tweak that to say "either 20 seconds have passed or horizontal accuracy is positive but below a certain value." That way, if it gets a sufficiently accurate location quickly, you don't have to wait an arbitrary amount of time.